# Error using Facebook Business Manager API to assign a user to a page: User is not Business Scoped

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to use the `/PAGE_ID/assigned_users` API call to assign a user as an ADVERTISER to a page in Business Manager.

The Page is already connected to Business Manager, and the user is also connected to Business Manager.

I thought that to get the Business Scoped User ID I just needed to issue the call /me/ids_for_business and use the ID that's returned (`data.id`).

When using that ID, this error is returned:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 1752100,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "User is not Business Scoped",
    "error_user_msg": "The user ID provided is not business scoped. Please provide a business or a system user ID",
    "fbtrace_id": "CDFlxxGLsTJ"
  }
}
```

How do I get the business scoped user ID if not by using the previously mentioned call?

FWIW using the user's actual Facebook ID returns the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this GET call to get your business users:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/[business_id]/business_users?access_token=[accesstoken]`